# How to separate the layer of the communication and processing?

Tags: c#, wcf

I created an application that provides several services. Each service provides a specific processing capabilities, except one service (that is the main service) that returns true or false to the clients which request if the specified processing capabilities is available or not.

Now I would modify the application, leaving the main service unchanged and adding the support for the installation of plugin with new processing capabilities: each plugin should add new processing capabilities without the need of implement a new service, but after installing the new plugin, a new service should be avaible. In this way, a plugin should not handle the communication layer. In other words, I would like to separate the layer of the communication and processing, in order to simplify the creation of new plugins.

Is it possible?

I could create two services: the main service and the service for processing.
The first service may be used by clients to know if a certain feature is present on the server (for example, clients may ask the server if it has installed the plugin that provides the functionality for solving differential equations).
The second service could be used to send a generic task and to receive a general result, for example:

```
Result executeTask(Task task);
```

where *Result* and *Task* are abstract classes...

For example, if I develop a plugin to solve the differential equations, I first create the classes for transferring data:

```
public class DifferentialEquationTask : Task
// This class contains the data of the differential equation to be solved.
...

public class DifferentialEquationResult : Result
// This class contains the the result.
...
```

Therefore, the client should instantiate a new object DifferentialEquationTask and pass it to the method of the second service:

```
DifferentialEquationTask myTask = new DifferentialEquationTask(...); 
...
Result result = executeTask(myTask); // called by basic application
// The second service receives myTask as a Task object.
// This Task object also contains the destination plugin, so myTask is send
// to the correct plugin, which converts it to DifferentialEquationTask
...
myResult = result as DifferentialEquationResult;
// received by the client
```

Moreover, each plugin should have a version for the application server and a version for the client application.

An alternative would be to include the service in the plugin itself: in this way, a new plugin should implement a new functionality and expose it via an additional service.
In summary, I thought the following two alternatives:

1. a main service to ask the server if it has a plugin or not, and a second service to deliver tasks at the correct plugin;
2. a main service to ask if the server has a plugin or not, and various additional services (an additional service for each plugin installed).

In order to choose the best approach, I could use the following requirements:

- Which of the two alternatives may provide better performance?
- What advantages would be obtained using a new service for each plugin than using a single service that delivers tasks at the correct plugin?
- Which of the two alternatives simplifies the development of a new plugin?

Being a novice, I was wondering if there was a better approach...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What "communication layer" stuff are you trying to avoid? WCF is taking care of the "communication layer".

Comment: I would like the creation of new plugins for the basic application does not involve the use of WCF: I wish that the communication is implemented only on the basic application, while the plugin should only add new processing capabilities. For example, if I want to create a new plugin that solves the differential equations, I would only implement classes that allow me to solve this kind of equations without having to implement a new service in the plugin.

Comment: How would the caller know that the new function exists? How would the caller know how to use the new functionality? How would the caller know how to pass parameters to the new functionality, and how would the communication layer know how to get the parameters to the new functionality? These are not new questions, and the answer, in general, is "it sounds great but it really isn't so great".

Comment: You are right. I added a more detailed example...

Comment: Thanks for the details. Why would the functionality not be present all of the time?

Comment: Because some functionality may require hardware resources not available on some servers (for example rendering requires a lot of resources): in this case the plugin will not be installed on these servers. Some functionality may be temporarily unavailable because already used by several clients...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the main service could maintain a dictionary of plugins, indexed by name. Then for a client to see if the server provides a particular service, all the main service has to do is look up the name in the dictionary. And to process, the service just has to call a method on the object that's in the value portion of the dictionary entry. An example:

You have three abstract classes: `Service`, `ServiceResult`, and `ServiceTask`. The contents of `ServiceTask` and `ServiceResult` aren't really important for this discussion. `Service` must have a parameterless constructor and a method called `Process` that takes a `ServiceTask` as its sole parameter. So your differential equation solver would look like:

```
public class DiffeqSolver : Service
{
    public DiffeqSolver()
    {
        // do any required initialization here
    }

    public ServiceResult Process(ServiceTask task)
    {
        DiffeqTask dtask = task as DiffeqTask;
        if (dtask == null)
        {
            // Error. User didn't pass a DiffeqTask.
            // Somehow communicate error back to client.
        }

        // Here, solve the diff eq and return the result.
    }
}
```

The main service is somehow notified of existing plugins. It maintains a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Service> Services = new Dictionary<string, Service>();
```

I assume you have some idea how you're going to load the plugins. What you want, in effect, is for the dictionary to contain:

```
Key = "DiffeqSolver", Value = new DiffeqSolver();
Key = "ServiceType1", Value = new ServiceType1();
etc., etc.
```

You can then have two methods for the main service:  `ServiceIsSupported` and `Process`:

```
bool ServiceIsSupported(string serviceName)
{
    return Services.ContainsKey(serviceName);
}

ServiceResult Process(string serviceName, ServiceTask task)
{
    Service srv;
    if (Services.TryGetValue(serviceName, out srv))
    {
        return srv.Process(task);
    }
    else
    {
        // The service isn't supported.
        // Return a failure result
        return FailedServiceResult;
    }
}
```

I've simplified that to some extent. In particular, I'm using a `Dictionary`, which is not thread safe. You'd want to use a `ConcurrentDictionary`, or use locks to synchronize access to your dictionary.

The more difficult part, I think, will be loading the plugins. But there are many available examples of creating a plugin architecture. I think you can find what you need.

Comment: Yes, your example more or less reflects the solution that I thought! The only difference is that I thought of using two WCF services (one to check if a certain plugin is supported, and the other for processing), but I think I will take inspiration from your example by implementing a single WCF service with the methods `ServiceIsSupported` and `Process`. Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: What are the limitations of using a single service (ie a single method `Process` for different types of processing)? Are there any disadvantages to using this approach that could be eliminated by using a multi-service approach (a service for each type of processing)?

Comment: @enzom83: If you have a separate service for each type of processing, then any time you add a new plugin, you'll have to add a new service. That makes adding a plugin somewhat more complicated. I don't see that there's any disadvantage to using a single `Process` method, and it's a lot easier to implement.